# installing gems fails with an error

Tags: ruby

I am getting the error below when I try to install gems. Has anyone seen this? I am on ubuntu 14.04 and I have ruby the latest version, built from source.

```
:~$ gem install sinatra
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

EDIT: I do have `zlib1g-dev` installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had this issue at work, you'll have to do:

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

If you installed zlib1g-dev AFTER ruby, you'll need to recompile ruby. In `rvm` that be something like:

`rvm reinstall [RUBY]`

Comment: Just saw your update - you'll have to recompile ruby after installing `zlib1g-dev` if you installed it after installing ruby.